# Why does Id increases by two instead of one using insert

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to understand after lots of hours and still cannot understand why it is happening.

I have created two tables with ALTER:

```
CREATE TABLE stores (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name TEXT
    -- add more fields if needed
);


CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL, 
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    image TEXT,
    url TEXT UNIQUE, 
    added_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, store_id)
);


ALTER TABLE products
ADD  CONSTRAINT "FK_products_stores" FOREIGN KEY ("store_id")
        REFERENCES stores (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

and everytime I am inserting a value to `products` by doing

```
INSERT
INTO
public.products(store_id, title, image, url)
VALUES((SELECT id FROM stores WHERE store_name = 'footish'),
       'Teva Flatform Universal Pride',
       'https://www.footish.se/sneakers/teva-flatform-universal-pride-t1116376',
       'https://www.footish.se/pub_images/large/teva-flatform-universal-pride-t1116376-p77148.jpg?timestamp=1623417840')
```

I can see that the column of id increases by two everytime I insert instead of one and I would like to know what is the reason behind that?

[image: dashboard]

I have not been able to figure out why and it would be nice to know! :)

Comment: It seems you have two stores with the name 'footish' (id 20 and 22). So you get two records inserted.

Comment: Hi @Steeeve - I realized the image was wrong and now its been updated. the id is `id SERIAL,` meaning. The store_id should be the same as footish has the number 3 inside the table of `Stores` - My question is why the id goes 20 22 and not 20 21?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be 3 reasons:

1. You've tried to create data but it failed. Even on failed creation and transaction rollback, a sequence does count. A used number will never be put back.
2. You're using a global sequence and created other data on other data meanwhile. Using a global sequence will always increase on any table data added, even on other tables be modified.
3. DB configuration for your sequence is set to stepsize/allocationsize=2. It can be configured however you want.

Overall it is not important. The most important thing is that it increases automatically and that even on a error/delete a already tried ID will never be put back.

If you want to have concrete information you need to procive the information about the sequence. You can check that using a SQL CLI or show it via DBeaver/....

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information! I do not believe I do get an error when inserting. I believe the 1 and 2 might not fit my "issue" but the 3 might be it. I was just curious because if I would have e.g. 4000 rows, that would be instead 8000 and not sure how that could perform the database when trying to earch. - Im using OMNIDB together with Postgresql. I havent set up anything about the sequence but maybe I did my mistake? Basically I just used the commands that I have posted as my question. Does the ALTER do it for me maybe?

Comment: However I do think there is a way I could do a "workaround" by doign: ```SELECT SETVAL((SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"products"', 'id')), (SELECT (MAX("id") + 1) FROM "products"), FALSE);```

Comment: The stepsize and higher INT values on the sequence have no impact on perfomance or data storage. Please dont do that workaround just to have a increasing ID in 1-step-sizes.
What you can do and test: `ALTER SEQUENCE stores_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1`. You might replace the name buit using this command you can set the step-size to 1. If this sequence is not shared it will increment by 1 always. Please note that you should check where this sequence is used. I got the feeling that you select the last number somewhere and thats why it increased and you dont noticed. nextval always means +1 for it!

Comment: Hmm is there anything I should change inside my ALTER to make it happend. I could re-create the tables and see if that is an issue or something like that. What do you think?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie what do you mean by "make it happen"? You dont need to recreate the DB/tables. Just check the sequence and how it is set up (it's so called DDL). Then just change the increasement to 1 and only use a sequence on 1 table.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! :D